# How we create pages to show records from a DataTable in a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataTable for example with 30 rows, but i only want to show from 0 to 10. And if the user clicks in a button (like forward or next), it will clear the Items in the DataGrid and shows between 10 and 20.

What i want is to separate records in a Collection of pages and then to show in DataGrid and control them with two buttons (forward or next, and backward or previous). It can be done? How?

In this case if it's possibly to separate the records in pages, we will not have problems to update the table in the DataBase?

And other thing, if i want to filter the records in my DataGrid, like if we have a TextBox, we type something, and then the DataGrid only shows the records with some value similar to that we have typed in the TextBox. Can it be done?

Comment: You are asking too much and showing us too little of your own efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try programmatically databinding to your DataGrid:

```
var perPage = 10;
var page = 2;

//Will bind rows 11-20 to the DataGrid
dataGrid.DataContext = DataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Skip(page*perPage).Take(perPage);
```

You'll need some simple buttons or links to implement operations like First, Previous, Next, Last, or page numbers to jump to.